# Unable to make build for microsoft hololens emulator through unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

I am trying to prepare build for hololens using unity 3D, I installed visual studio community 2015 with updates, microsoft hololens emulator 10.0.14393.0, Windows SDK-10.0.14393.33. Facing an odd issue when trying to make build getting following error:

> IOException: Win32 IO returned 112. Path: C:\Program Files\Unity HoloLens 5.4.0f3-HTP\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\MetroSupport\Players\UAP\dotnet\x64\debug\UnityPlayer_UAP_x64_debug_dotnet.pdb" or ".\App\Players\UAP\x64\debug\UnityPlayer_UAP_x64_debug_dotnet.pdb
>   System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:124)
>   PostProcessWinRT.CopyPlayerFiles (System.String[] extensions) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinRT/SharedSources/CSharp/PostProcessWinRT.cs:830)
>   PostProcessUAPDotNet.CopyPlayerFiles () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessUAPDotNet.cs:69)
>   PostProcessWinRT.Process () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinRT/SharedSources/CSharp/PostProcessWinRT.cs:151)
>   UnityEditor.Metro.BuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/ExtensionModule.cs:130)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Note: Before building the app I selected recommended option in unity editor like

- SDK: Universal 10
- UWP Build Type : D3D
- Build and run on : Local machine.
- PLayer settings checked : Virtual realty SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Found it elsewhere - Error 112 is "not enough space on disk". AKA, your hard drive is full, delete some stuff.

Comment: +1 Thanks , I figured it out later that day, just came back after a long time, Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Player Settings: Virtual Reality SDK is wrong it should be the SDK for hololens specifically.